# How can I prevent from hard coding the code below?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a course model and a lesson model. When I nest these two model in my route.rb, I get the following path.

```
      course_lessons GET    /courses/:course_id/lessons(.:format)          lessons#index
                     POST   /courses/:course_id/lessons(.:format)          lessons#create
   new_course_lesson GET    /courses/:course_id/lessons/new(.:format)      lessons#new
  edit_course_lesson GET    /courses/:course_id/lessons/:id/edit(.:format) lessons#edit
       course_lesson GET    /courses/:course_id/lessons/:id(.:format)      lessons#show
                     PATCH  /courses/:course_id/lessons/:id(.:format)      lessons#update
                     PUT    /courses/:course_id/lessons/:id(.:format)      lessons#update
                     DELETE /courses/:course_id/lessons/:id(.:format)      lessons#destroy
             courses GET    /courses(.:format)                             courses#index
                     POST   /courses(.:format)                             courses#create
          new_course GET    /courses/new(.:format)                         courses#new
         edit_course GET    /courses/:id/edit(.:format)                    courses#edit
              course GET    /courses/:id(.:format)                         courses#show
                     PATCH  /courses/:id(.:format)                         courses#update
                     PUT    /courses/:id(.:format)                         courses#update
                     DELETE /courses/:id(.:format)                         courses#destroy
```

With this, I seem to have to hard code the course_id`<li><%= link_to "new lesson", new_course_lesson_path(course_id: 1) %></li>`in my view files to create a lesson which belongs to a certain course.

But when I don't nest the course and lesson in my route.rb file, I am able to go to the new.html.rb file for a lesson and create a lesson and then assign a course_id to the lesson.

But I feel that nesting the two resources is much cleaner than having them separate.

Which is better?And is there a way to prevent hard coding the course_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, do not hard code. It should be:

```
<li>
  <%= link_to "new lesson", new_course_lesson_path(@course) %>
</li>
```

And you should instantiate `@course` in whatever action is associated with the view that includes the above code.

So, let's say, for the sake of example, that `@course` has an id of 2. Then,

```
<%= link_to "new lesson", new_course_lesson_path(@course) %>
```

Will create a link that, when clicked, routes to:

```
/courses/2/lessons/new
```

Now, there are some different ways to do this. Say, for example, that your `link_to` is on the view of your `courses#show` action. In that case, your `params` will include an `id` value for the current course. If that was the course with the `id=2`, then you would have `params[:id] = 2`. In that case, you could do:

```
<%= link_to "new lesson", new_course_lesson_path(id: params[:id]) %>
```

In this case, you are not instantiating `@course`. Which is OK. You can tell Rails what you want in whatever way is best matched to your context. This would, again, give a link that, when clicked, routes to:

```
/courses/2/lessons/new
```

"Which is better" is possibly subject to opinion. But, given your brief description, nesting routes seems like a grand idea.

Comment: oh, ok so I have to instantiate @course in my lessons_controller.rb. What would be the reason behind this instantiation?